# Ruby parse comma separated text file

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need some help with a Ruby script I can call from the console. The script needs to parse a simple .txt file with comma separated values.

```
value 1, value2, value3, etc...
```

The values needs to be added to the database.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
array = File.read("csv_file.txt").split(",").map(&:strip)
```

You will get the values in the array and use it to store to database. If you want more functions, you can make use of [`FasterCSV` gem](http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/).

Comment: BTW: love this short version.

Comment: Be careful when there are values like "string with , character"

Comment: @J-_-L in that case the input file should represent such values in a special format. CSV format escapes such values by wrapping a quote around the values with commas I believe.

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty solution:

```
result = []
File.open("<path-to-file>","r") do |handle|
  handle.each_line do |line|
    result << line.split(",").strip
  end
end # closes automatically when EOF reached

result.flatten!
result # => big array of values
```

Now you can iterate the result array and save the values to the database.

This simple file iteration **doesn't** take care for order or special fields, because it wasn't mentioned in the question.

Comment: As you see in the other answers, you also can use CSV gems.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby 1.9.2 has a very good CSV library which is useful for this stuff: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/csv/rdoc/index.html

On earlier versions of Ruby you could use http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/ (which essentially became CSV in 1.9.2)

You could do it manually by reading the file into a string and using `.split(',')` but I'd go with one of the libraries above.

Comment: It depends on. An extra gem or lib can have load/performance/RAM costs. But in general it's okay to use a lib for such cases.

Answer (score 0):

Something easy to get you started:

```
IO.readlines("csv_file.txt", '').each do |line|
  values = line.split(",").collect(&:strip)
  # do something with the values?
end
```

Hope this helps.